# How To Reflect The Website Authentication Done With Python Script Into The Browser?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

My question may sound stupid, but I just want to know if this is possible to browse the web pages which needs authentication after doing the authentication with python requests library.

I've a script to login into the application, which successfully authenticate the user into application, but is there a way to reflect that in a browser like in Chrome? so that user could directly access the authenticated page without having to fill the form and login. It's happening inside my application, so I'm not breaching any privacy policy of such things. 
Any suggestions would be great.

For example I authenticated myself into http://example.com/login through the script, I want to be able to directly browse http://example.com/user/home in the browser. How this could be possible?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to have your python application log in the web application, and the have it request an token. Then the script will open the browser, passing along the token. Your web application takes that token and uses it in lieu of the login form to authenticate your user and create their session.

Take a look at OAuth, I think it has specific workflows for this kind of scenario. Otherwise you can craft your own.

Comment: Thanks @Will Hartung, I got your idea, but in this case actually I don't want to open up a next window in the browser, actually I wanted to handle this behind the scene. I've a script that automatically login the user into the other application, the only problem here seems that it won't work in the browser even though it works inside the python script.